# How to save ole object (contains jpg,excel, pdf file)to file in powerbuilder

Tags: oracle, blob, ole, powerbuilder

I have saved data in format of blob using powerbuilder ole control in oracle.

Now we want to convert these blob to files,
files are of different format(PDF, JPG,EXCEL,TEXT,DOC)

There are more than 1 Million files so it is not easy to do manually open and save using olecontrol.

Can we do it through script auto saving of blob to file in powerbuilder

Comment: The blob are already the final files, except that the files have no bad extension? If so, I would give a try with the libmagic to determine the file type from its content. Perhaps that you could use a dll form of the libmagic to integrate with PB.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible:

1. Write a cursor in PowerBuilder embedded SQL to get for each record in your blob table the key and the and file extension (if you have those). The syntax for that kind of thing looks like this:

   ```
   Long ll_Key
   String ls_Ext
       DECLARE GetBlobCursor CURSOR FOR  
       SELECT blob_key,   
              blob_extension  
         FROM blob_table  ;
   /* need to loop here while SQLCA.SQLCode is good */
        FETCH GetBlobCursor   
         INTO :ll_Key,   
              :ls_Ext  ;
   ```
2. Use a SELECTBLOB embedded SQL statement to get the blob data into a PowerBuilder BLOB variable:

   ```
       Blob lblob_File
   SELECTBLOB fileblob 
     INTO :lblob_File 
     FROM blobtable 
    WHERE blob_key = :ll_Key ;
   ```
3. Use FileOpen and FileWrite to write the blob with a valid file name and extension:

   ```
   Long ll_Loops, ll_Step
   Int li_File
   String ls_Path
   ls_Path = "<where do you want me?>." + String(ll_Key) + "." + ls_Ext
   li_File = FileOpen(ls_Path, StreamMode!, Write!, LockWrite!, Append!)
   If li_File > 0 Then
       // Determine how many times to call FileWrite
       ll_FileLen = Len(lblob_File)
       If ll_FileLen > 32765 Then
           If Mod(ll_FileLen, 32765) = 0 Then
               ll_Loops = ll_FileLen/32765
           Else
               ll_Loops = (ll_FileLen/32765) + 1
           End If
       Else
           ll_Loops = 1
       End If
       For ll_Step = 1 To ll_Loops
           FileWrite(li_File,BlobMid(lblob_File,((ll_Step - 1)*32765) + 1, 32765))
       Next
   Else
       //log the error, or handle
   End If
   FileClose(li_File)
   ```

Hope that gets you started.